# Check user permissions in vue js laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I have a Laravel & Vue project, in my middleware I have:

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $user = auth()->user();
        
    if ($user->hasRole('admin')) {
        return $next($request);
    } else {
        if ($user->hasRole('staff')) {
            return redirect()->route(get_default_route_by_user($user));
        }
    
    ...
```

And in my Blade files I use below code and it works perfectly:

```php
@if($service->visible_to_public == '1')
    // Do something
@elseif (auth()->user()->hasRole('admin'))
    // Do something else
```

How could I, in my Vue files, use the same if conditions as in my Blade files? I tried the below code **but It is not working**. I am absolutely new to Javascript.

```html
<div v-if="service.visible_to_public == 1">
  Do something
</div>
    
<div v-else-if="(auth()->user()->hasRole('admin'))">
  do something else
</div>
```

Comment: i recommend you to use [inertia](https://inertiajs.com/) for this. is one of the best ways to use laravel + vue together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to rewrite your functions in JS and get the user details from the api, backend (PHP) and frontend (Vue.js) are completely independant.

**An example :**

1/ get logged user details, roles, permissions... with GET "/auth/me", store this in your app (vue store, local storage...)

2/ write a function to test if the user has a specific role

```
function hasRole(user, role) {
  if(!user || !user.role)
    return false

  if(user.role === 'super-admin')
    return true

  return role === user.role
}
```

You can do the same with permissions :

```
function hasPermission(user, permission) {
  if(!user || !user.permissions)
    return false

  if(user.role === 'super-admin')
    return true

  if(Array.isArray(permission))
    return user.permissions.some(i => permission.includes(i))
  else
    return user.permissions.includes(permission)
}
```